# Doxygen not showing the public, non-static member function

Tags: doxygen

I have been struggling with getting the below code excerpt's documentation appear properly with `doxygen`.

I have searched online for the problem; yet, it seems that the documentation not showing up is mostly due to the member function/variable being private. Even though I seem to be documenting a public member function, which is also non-static, I can't get `doxygen` working properly. I would appreciate any help of yours.

```cpp
/**
 * @brief Algorithm abstraction.
 *
 * @tparam float_t `float` or `double`.
 * @tparam int_t `int64_t` or similar.
 * @tparam StepPolicy Policy for selecting a step-size.
 * @tparam OraclePolicy Policy for getting first-order information.
 */
template <class float_t, class int_t, template <class, class> class StepPolicy,
          template <class, class> class OraclePolicy>
struct Algorithm : public StepPolicy<float_t, int_t>,
                   public OraclePolicy<float_t, int_t> {
  /**
   * @brief Default constructor.
   *
   */
  Algorithm() = default;
  /**
   * @brief Constructor with a step-size.
   *
   * @param[in] step Non-negative step-size value.
   */
  Algorithm(float_t step) : StepPolicy<float_t, int_t>{step} {}

  /**
   * @brief Set the initial step-size of the algorithm.
   *
   * @param[in] step Non-negative step-size value.
   */
  void set_stepsize(float_t step) { StepPolicy<float_t, int_t>::set(step); }
  /**
   * @brief Get the current step-size of the algorithm.
   *
   * This does *not* change the state of StepPolicy.
   *
   * @return float_t Current step-size.
   */
  float_t get_stepsize() const { return StepPolicy<float_t, int_t>::get(); }
  /**
   * @brief Get current step-size based on the algorithm's state.
   *
   * @param[in] k Current iteration count.
   * @param[in] N Dimension of `x` and `dx`.
   * @param[in] x Current decision vector.
   * @param[in] dx Current first-order information.
   * @return float_t Current step-size.
   */
  float_t get_stepsize(const int_t k, const int_t N, const float_t *x,
                       const float_t *dx) {
    return StepPolicy<float_t, int_t>::get(k, N, x, dx);
  }

private:
  int_t k{0};
};
```

I am not sure if `doxygen` has anything to do with *valid* code excerpts, but the above code does indeed compile. Does it have anything to do with templates and inheritance? Am I missing something? I mean, for non-inheriting template classes, `doxygen` can do its job.

By the way, I do not have any concrete `StepPolicy` or `OraclePolicy` somewhere in my directories. Moreover, I can see the constructors getting documented properly. I am just stuck.

I can share my `Doxygen` file here, which is basically just the defaults overridden in `MathJax`-related settings.

Thank you, in advance, for your time.

Comment: Looks like doxygen does not like: Algorithm(float_t step) : StepPolicy<float_t, int_t>{step} {} "solutions" are at the moment moving it to the end of the struct or using an #ifdef or \cond construct not including it in the documentation (or part of it).

Comment: Looks like you have nailed it, @albert. Thank you. Would you mind sharing this as an answer, maybe elaborating on how you have found out that doxygen did not like the mentioned overload of the constructor as well as the #ifdef/\cond trick? Maybe this is trivial for you, but for me it was a bit obscure. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you think that it is better to declare all the members and document them, and then give out-of-class definitions below, inside the same translational unit?

Comment: I don't have an opinion about the order of the declarations, but it is to the best of my knowledge, quite common to start with constructors and destructors in the class. I "found" just by some, educated, guessing and the fact that I never saw constructs with to sets of {} before. Regarding \cond see documentation where it is explained that parts are left out. Thanks for submitting a bug report bugzilla bug 790788)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with `v1.8.14`, there is no such a problem. Apparently, the question was a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790788), which has been **fixed** by the maintainers of `doxygen`.